# Calling on a specific column from a reactive expression (R shiny)

Tags: r, proxy, shiny, leaflet, reactive

I understand the syntax of taking your Spatial Polygon Data Frame and building a subset using a reactive expression. For instance, allowing a slider as a user input to narrow the range of data you want to display:

```
ui <- fluidPage(  
sliderInput("range", "Scores", min(SPDF@data$Total_Score), max(SPDF@data$Total_Score),value = range(SPDF@data$Total_Score), step = 0.5)
)

server <- function(input, output) {

final.dat <- reactive({SPDF[SPDF@data$Total_Score >= input$range[1] & SPDF@data$Total_Score <= input$range[2],]
})
}
```

And I know I can then assign final.dat() as the data in subsequent renderings: eg output$map <- renderLeaflet({leaflet(final.dat())}). However, I'm trying to use leafletProxy to update my map, and I'm having trouble filling my polygons and building a new legend based on the new subset. I cannot refer to the desired column of my Spatial Polygon Data Frame using the SPDF@data$column syntax anymore because it's now the function final.dat(). I've tried assigning final.dat() a variable and then using the $column syntax, but it errors (see code below). I've also tried replacing the SPDF$Column with SPDF@data$Column and with just ~Column, and all versions result in an error. Or the map just never plots.

Errors include:
Warning: Error in pal2: unused argument (Total_Score)
ERROR: [on_request_read] connection reset by peer

How do you refer to a column once you've used a reactive expression and created a function in place of your Spatial Polygon Data Frame? Specifically, when referring to the column for the fillColor argument in addPolygon() and the values argument in addLegend(). Can anyone see why my code below is not producing a map (just the slider)? Thanks so much!

FULL CODE:

```
ui <- fluidPage(  
leafletOutput("map"),
sliderInput("range", "Scores", min(SPDF@data$Total_Score),  
max(SPDF@data$Total_Score),value = range(SPDF@data$Total_Score), step = 0.5)
)

server <- function(input, output) {
# Color palette
pal <- colorNumeric(palette = "YlOrRd", domain = SPDF$Total_Score)

# Initial Map
output$map <- renderLeaflet({leaflet() %>% 
  addTiles() %>%
  addPolygons(data=SPDF,
    fillColor = ~pal(Total_Score),
    weight = 0.5,
    opacity = 1,
    color = "white") %>%
  addLegend(position = "bottomleft",pal = pal, opacity = 0.7, values = SPDF$Total_Score, title = "<strong>Total Score</strong>")
})

# Subset data
final.dat <- reactive({
SPDF[SPDF@data$Total_Score >= input$range[1] & SPDF@data$Total_Score <= input$range[2],]
})

# New color palette
pal2 <-  reactive({ 
SPDF <- final.dat()  
colorNumeric(palette = "YlOrRd", domain = SPDF$Total_Score)
})

# Leaflet Proxy to update map
observe({
SPDF <- final.dat() 
leafletProxy("map", data = SPDF) %>%
  clearShapes() %>%
  clearControls() %>%
  addPolygons(
    fillColor = ~pal2(Total_Score),
    weight = 0.5,
    opacity = 1,
    color = "white") %>%
  addLegend(position = "bottomleft",pal = pal2, opacity = 0.7, values = SPDF$Total_Score, title = "<strong>Total Score</strong>")
})
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: For reasons like this I prefer to use `reactiveValues` and `observe` instead of `reactive`. Apparently it is bad style, but problems like this always arise otherwise.

Comment: My actual code is quite a bit longer and has more inputs, but the code I pasted has all the components that I'm having trouble with. So, with the large code, I've gotten a couple of different errors as I've been troubleshooting. I remember one regarding "not having metadata".  I also have this one: "Warning: Error in as.vector: cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'list'
ERROR: [on_request_read] connection reset by peer." The shiny web app just closes automatically when that occurs. And right now the code I have pasted above is just not updating the map, though there are no errors.

Comment: Well, if the code provided is running without error, then I think the observe() is not working how you want. Does it have to be an observe?  Could you not just create a default map based on the default slider inputs and let that map be reactive to the slider? The unfilled map plus the observe seems unnecessary (in addition to not working).

Comment: I'm basing my use of observe and leafletProxy on Rstudio's tutorial [here](https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/shiny.html). Also - maybe I should have posted the whole code - but I do actually have 4 sliders that have inputs that build my default map, and I'm trying to create another slider that then filters the polygons on the map by score, hence leafletProxy. That is the part of the code I'm struggling with.

Comment: Fair enough. So if I'm understanding correctly, you don't want the map redrawn as the inputs change.  You want items added (or substracted then added back using new inputs). My suggestions are: 1) It appears that each element you want changed should get its own observe() treatment (legend and filled in polygons).  Trying to put them together probably might mess it up (there are some comments about this in the documentation you provided).  2) For your legend colors, I think you need to call the color palette using pal2() within the reactive setting the same way you call the reactive data.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! I'd actually just fixed the pal2() part of the code, but there are still errors. I separated the legend into a different observe() treatment as suggested. I'm now getting a new error: Warning: Error in <-: invalid (NULL) left side of assignment. I think I'll go ahead and post the whole code in a new post. It may be easier for people to troubleshoot. Though I do think there is just one major misunderstanding of how things work that is happening in both this subset of the code and the larger code. Thanks again!